# Highest Common Factor C#

Tags: c#

I have the current coding and I feel as if it is close to what I need but I can't seem to get it to work for what I want. I am trying to get it to output the highest common factor of the two numbers entered.

```
            i = myInt;

            {
                if (myInt % i == 0 && myInt2 % i == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("Your GCF is...");
                    Console.Write("{0} ", i);
                    Console.ReadLine();

                }
                else
                    i--;
                goto;
            }
```

Comment: Goto? I think I just threw up in my mouth a little.

Comment: Is this homework? Second remove the goto!

Comment: So what isn't working?  Does it produce errors, are you getting false positives, no answer, is it running forever, is it giving wrong answers, does it only sometimes work, have you not actually run it yet, does it not compile, [...]?

Comment: Even if noone cares how you homework looks like, please make sure to provide concise sample here. Extract code that you have question about into separate function and post just it, remove all the rest like `Write` and `ReadLine`... Expecting `int ComputeGCF(int first, int second)....` in this question.

Comment: Does this `goto` even work? I thought it required an identifier/label to work? (LINQPad doesn't compile it anyway)

Comment: I'm pretty new to C# and someone told me to use goto, what else is there that I can use? Also, I haven't been able to get it to run because it was telling me something was wrong with the goto.

Comment: You are not calculating the GCF anywhere! See [Greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) (Wikipedia)

Comment: for the line `i = myInt` do you care if myInt is larger or smaller than myInt2? What do you think this would do for your execution time if myInt were 4,000,000,000 and myInt2 = 3?

Comment: Tell the Individual who told you to use GOTO that this is not VB LOL

Comment: Use the [while](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd(v=vs.71).aspx) statement to make a loop, not a `goto`.

Comment: why did his question get down voted? It's obvious that he is new to C#. @JoelEtherton, Hilarious comment!!

Comment: @AthensHolloway It was likely downvoted because the asker put no effort into the question.  He put his entire code base into the question, said "it don't work" and "plz fix".  He made no effort to solve his own problem, determine what the actual problem was, explain what he has done, determine what section of his code base is causing the problem, etc.  Apparent lack of effort in the question is often met with downvotes.  (And he used a GOTO.)

Comment: I am sorry I have also never used stack overflow before it was suggested to me and I thought I would try it out.

Comment: @user1783636 - Don't worry. It's a learning process - everyone was new at one point. If you edit your question along the lines that Servy pointed out, you might get some upvotes too.  Even if you don't, you'll now know how to ask a better question next time.

Comment: @user1783636 Don't worry, new users often have trouble adapting to the site.  You can edit your question at any time, so simply fix the problems that have been mentioned.  Remove the code that isn't related to your problem, add more information about what is and isn't working, and so on.  Don't just give up and write off the site.  Instead you just need to realize that the value you get from the site is proportional to what you put in.  Good questions can get great answers, and questions that took little effort to write often get answers with equally low effort put into them.

Comment: @Servy good point! Your comment is more helpful to user1783636 than the actual attempts to answer the question in my opinion.

Comment: @Servy For now I am just going to study up a bit on     while loops, if I have troubles from there I will be sure to come back for help. Thank you everyone

Comment: @Tristan - Sounds like a good plan.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As others said in comments, you should really avoid `goto` statements because they are bad practice, especially when you are learning your college course of programming (that usually should conform to structural programming). Instead use `while` loop (or any other) with two conditions as you can see in the example. Also, I think that you should start your search from the smaller number (the first entered does not need to be smaller one) which is a little improvement in terms of performance. This is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{    
    string myInput;
    int myInt;
    string myInput2;
    int myInt2;
    int i;

    Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
    myInput = Console.ReadLine();
    myInt = Int32.Parse(myInput);

    Console.Write("Please enter another number: ");
    myInput2 = Console.ReadLine();
    myInt2 = Int32.Parse(myInput2);

    i = myInt > myInt2 ? myInt2 : myInt;
    bool found = false;
    while(!found && i>0)
    {
        if (myInt % i == 0 && myInt2 % i == 0)
        {
            Console.Write("Your GCF is...");
            Console.Write("{0} ", i);
            Console.ReadLine();
            found = true;
        }
        else
            i--;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I included the other possible solution thanks to @Servy

```
bool found = false;
for( i = Math.Min(myInt, myInt2); !found && i>0; i--)
{
    if (myInt % i == 0 && myInt2 % i == 0)
    {
        Console.Write("Your GCF is...");
        Console.Write("{0} ", i);
        Console.ReadLine();
        found = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd put `{}`'s around the else, but that's a style thing.  No different functionally, until you accidentally add a new line that should be in the else and isn't.

Comment: @Bobson good point, I always do, just didn't want to change OP's code significantly. Nevertheless, I regularly receive questions like "Do I need those brackets when I have only one statement?"

Comment: Rather than `myInt > myInt2 ? myInt2 : myInt;` I would use `Math.Max`.  It makes the intent clearer.  Also you can use a `for` loop rather than a `while`, since you're creating a loop variable at the start, and decrimenting it each time in a while.  Again, just makes the intent clearer more than any change in actual functionality.  Oh, and there's no need for a boolean `found`.  Since you only ever set it to true at the "end" of your loop, you can effectively make the `if` the expression in the `for`/`while` condition; it will clean up the code.

Comment: @Servy If I used Math.Max then I would need to explain what than method means (he is learning basics remember). For loop shouldn't be used here because the loop should run until the GCF is found, or in cases when not found until the counter reaches 0. Ideally  i should hold the GCF value when finished with loop. Again, it's not structural programming when you exit from for loop before the counter condition is met.

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick You think that `Math.Max` is conceptually harder to understand than using a conditional operator?  I...disagree.  A `for` loop is simply a `while` loop that defines a variable first and runs a statement after the end of the body; no more, no less.  It's certainly possible to use a `for` to continue until the GCF is found.  Who cares about whether the program is "structural programming" or not?  The code would work, it would be simpler, easier to read, and run equally well.  If it no long falls into some arbitrary category then I see no value lost.

Comment: @Servy Well, I don't want to argue with you about that, but have you tried to draw an algorithm for that for loop of yours that exits prematurely, well that is something his professor doesn't want to see and I am trying to teach him how it should be done by the book. I'm not writing the code to show how good programmer I am but to help him.

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick Why do you insist on saying that the `for` loop should exit prematurely?  It should exit when the condition defining it's when it should exit says it should exit.  `for` loops don't need to have a constant number of iterations either in practice or conceptually.  It really is just a wrapper around a `while` loop, and you should think of them that way, not as just magic code that executes a block X times.  *That's* the conceptual lack of understanding that needs to be avoided.

Comment: @Servy And yes I think that he has already seen a ternary operator because that is something that you read about within first 10 pages of any programming book (C, C++, C#) but you don't see Math.Max (Math.Min should be used in this case) is something that you can easily find within first few chapters.

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick Your assumption that the conditional operator is discussed in all early programming books is false.  I have read a number of them, and never seen it early on, nor encouraged in intro books.  All early books I've seen explicitly write out the `if` statement (as I would suggest for any new programmer).  As for `Math.Max`, one doesn't need to be explained what it does, it takes the max of the two values; it reads exactly like what it does, that's what makes it preferable to your statement.

Comment: @Servy Well I am teaching C on introductory level on the University and have a lot of experience about that. It is something that should be avoided as a bad practice. It's not structural, you can't draw it on algorithm.

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick What?  What do you mean by: "It's not structural, you can't draw it on algorithm."  I would write it such that it reads exactly as the algorithm is written, and it wouldn't be *substantially* different from your code; functionally it would be identical.

Comment: @Servy Try to draw it. If you don't like my answer you are welcome to downvote it, we don't need to argue about it. And I know that in whichever book you read, ternary operator ? is mentioned at the beginning just because it was (until recently) the only such operator.

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick Draw what, how do you represent programming concepts as images?  I find that the better test of the quality of code is asking someone to "explain" it.  Read what it does in English.  If it's easy, and the mapping between the written description and the code is straightforward then it's good, if not, it isn't.  As I've said, I've read several into to programming books, none of them reference the conditional operator at the very start

Comment: @Servy And another thing, can you write that algorithm of yours in other languages like FORTRAN or any other where you can't define complex conditions for for loops?

Comment: @Servy And yes, people learn writing algorithms on their introductory courses of programming

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick Not having done FORTRAN development I couldn't speak to using it as a language.  My suggestion would work just fine in c/c++/c#/Java, and other c-based languages. That's what the OP is clearly working with.  I don't ensure every piece of C# code I write easily maps to FORTRAN, it's just not a consideration I made when developing.  Where did I say that algorithms shouldn't be or aren't taught in an intro programming course?

Comment: @Servy That was my point from the very beginning but it seems like you don't understand that. Although any C like programming language supports it, it is not the best practice to use for loop like that. That is why while and do-while loops exist, to be used when it is not clear how many iterations there will be. It seems like you never learned that. Of course, when you program, you can use whatever suits you, but I'm talking about the fundamentals about which you apparently don't have a clue. Programming concepts should be learned regardless of the programming language that is used.

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick What's your basis for assuming I'm not familiar with that concept?  I specifically said that I feel that those who believe a `for` loop is used solely for running a block of code a fixed number of times don't understand what a `for` loop is, or how to properly use it, and likewise those who teach that it should *only* be used that way are spreading misconceptions.  A `for` loop is nothing more than a `while` loop that runs a single statement before it starts and another statement at the end of each loop.  It is not *just* a way to count from 0 to n by one.

Comment: @Servy I don't know and I don't care how you feel about that, I'm just saying how it is treated in the educational community and how it is taught. I can't believe that this is so important to you and can't figure out what you are trying to accomplish with these comments.

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick Well, first off, you seem to think that your views are absolute and universally shared; they are not.  I know quite a number of people who do not share your views, including, among others, professors teaching university courses.  As for what I'm trying to accomplish, I was at first trying to help you write better code, and, indirectly, help the OP and future readers write better code.  Once it became clear that you both though your answer was preferable and are sharing those beliefs with many others, I continued explaining my points to hopefully benefit students of yours.

Comment: @Servy These are not my views, but from those who know much more than me. Thank you for all that enlightenment of yours, I added your version to my answer, I hope you are satisfied. I think that you don't know any professor that teaches like that on the University and that you are bluffing but never mind ;-).

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick I find it odd that you don't think they're you're views.  What are your views if these aren't it?  They may not be *solely* your views; I certainly agree with that.  I know lots of people who don't have a string understanding of what a `for` loop really is, so the fact that this view is shared with many others is undoubtedly true.  I find it absurd that you think no teacher would ever teach what a `for` loop actually does, rather than stating that it's a magic series of characters that you must always use to increment a variable from 0 to a fixed value.

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick - For what it's worth, in my C++ classes for my CS major (before they switched to Java), the professors preferred complex `for` statements to conditional-break `while` loops.

Comment: @Servy It wasn't my point at all, for is just what you say it is, but in C like syntax, it has more equipment. If you look some libraries, written by best programmers in the world, you can always find for loop s that are used in these cases instead of while, and it's OK. I just want to influence people at the beginning to see the differences. After that, they can use them however they want and that is just fine.

Comment: @Bobson - Did the professors also favor complex `for` loops over `while` loops?

Comment: @Bobson I do that also, I favor for loops instead of while because they are easier for learning. But we were discussing for loops with complex conditions that can exit earlier. Did they favored that?

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick - Y'know?  I don't remember either way. I have the feeling that they did, with a test statement that included a check as to whether we had a result, rather than using a flag variable that said to stop.  But I haven't looked at that code in years, if I even still have it.

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick - No, the middle argument to the for loop.  Something like `for (int i = Math.Min(myInt, myInt2); result == -1 && i>0; i--)`, assuming we didn't return `result` from the middle of the function (in which case it wouldn't be in the loop test).  And assuming I'm remembering correctly.

Comment: @Servy Servy, you owe me a downvote delete, I edited the answer. No heartfeelings, it is good to discus these issues and I think that we did some good work since others joined discussion.

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick I wouldn't downvote any answer based solely on the issues that I've mentioned in the comments to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
        {
label:
            if (myInt % i == 0 && myInt2 % i == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("Your GCF is...");
                Console.Write("{0} ", i);
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
            else
                i--;
            goto label;
        }
```

will do. However, this is a very bad idea. Rather learn how to use `while`.

Comment: Looks like you should refactor that and get rid of that GOTO...YUK...!

Comment: While this is *better* than the OP's code, that's a bit like saying that owing someone $9,999.99 is better than owing them $10,000.  It's the kind of difference that just isn't worth pointing out.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Yossarian is showing the OP what can be changed to get his code to work, and also tells him it'd be better to use `while`.